# React Native Java Script import array of words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to import an array of words into my hangman game, however, I am encountering an error

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
Word
/src/components/Word.js:8:20
5 |
6 |  return (
7 |

> 8 |      {selectedWord.split('').map((letter, i) => {
> |                   ^
> 9 |        return (
> 10 |          
> 11 |            {correctLetters.includes(letter) ? letter : ''}

Here is the Words.js file where the error appears to be occurring on line 8:

```js
import React from 'react';

// rendering the list of correct words
const Word = ({ selectedWord, correctLetters }) => {

  return (
    <div className="word">
      {selectedWord.split('').map((letter, i) => {
        return (
          <span className="letter" key={i}>
            {correctLetters.includes(letter) ? letter : ''}
          </span>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Word
```

Any help to fix this problem would be much appreciated,
Thanks :)

Comment: Your hangmanarray export is a function, so your rename as words is still a function

Comment: you can return `words` from words.js and import as 
`import {words} from "./components/words";`

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting `hangmanArray` as a function that returns the words when executed. Either you should call it before using and store in a variable or export the `words` array directly.

`const words = hangmanArray()`